# Kendo UI Grid for Angular 2 Server Side Sorting

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm following this [Grid Sorting example](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/#toc-sorting) on the Kendo documentation, but I need guidance in getting this to work as a server-side sort instead of a client-side sort.

I'm thinking the "toOdataString()" method used in their [Data-Binding example](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/) should somehow be able to accept the sortDescriptors as well.  Can anyone advise on whether or not this is supported, and if so, how do I achieve it?

Thanks a mil'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data binding example that you linked also supports sorting you just need to enable it:

1. Enable the option on the Grid:

   ```
   [sortable]="{ mode: 'multiple' }"
   [sort]="sort"
   ```
2. Pass the sort parameters in the dataStateChange event:

   ```
   this.grid.dataStateChange
       .do(({ skip, take, sort }: DataStateChangeEvent) => {
           this.skip = skip;
           this.pageSize = take;
           this.sort = sort;
       })
       .subscribe(x => this.service.query(x));
   ```

Check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hL3IbJWE49UpPOzyDQz7?p=preview).